# Constructor from initializer_list

Tags: c++, constructor, initializer-list

I am implementing a container in c++, a wrapper for an array in fact. I am not sure how to implement a constructor from initializer_list. I end up with this implementation but it seems to me really ugly. So could be an array allocated in a heap initialized by an initializer_list. Or is there an elegant way how to do it?

```
template <typename T> class sequence {
public:
    sequence (size_t n): _data {new T[n]}, _size {n} {};
    sequence (std::initializer_list<T> source);
    ~sequence() { delete[] _data; };
private:
    pointer     _data;
    size_type   _size;
};

//Initializer list constructor
template <class T> sequence<T>::sequence (std::initializer_list<T> source)
: sequence(source.size()) {
    auto iterator = source.begin();
    for ( int i=0; i < _size; i++) {
        _data[i] = *iterator;
        ++iterator;
    }
};
```

Comment: [FYI] you never allocated `_data` and you should get out of the habit of preceding variable names with `_`.

Comment: You are wrong, I have allocated it. I know about the _ naming problems. I actually don't use that naming style. I only didnt want to rewrite this snipest of code. But thanks for your comment.

Comment: Have a std::vector as member and do not modify the size of the vector (besides during construction)

Comment: @JiříLechner No where in `sequence (std::initializer_list<T> source);` do you call `new`.  `sequence (size_t n): _data {new T[n]}, _size {n} {};` is not called when you use `sequence (std::initializer_list<T> source);`

Comment: Well, I intend to implement my vector based on the sequence class so using std::vector seems to me like cheating. I am doing it mostly for educational reasons but it could be good choice eventually.

Comment: @NathanOliver Are you sure? It seems to me the constructor chaining is working and `:sequence(source.size())` in the initialization list of the constructor `sequence(std::initializer_list<T>)` calls the converse constructor.

Comment: @NathanOliver I think he used *delegating constructor*

Comment: Oh I'm sorry.  I thought it was a member variable.  It is delegating.

Answer (score 6):

Depends on what you're trying to do.

If you're actually needing to use a sequence with bounded size, as determined at compile-time, then use `std::array<T,std::size_t>`, which is a wrapper around a C-style array (like what you are implementing), introduced in C++11.

However, as you said in one of your comments, you're doing this mostly for educational purposes.  In that case, what you have is decent.  The syntax could be cleaned up a little.  Consider:

```
//Initializer list constructor
template <class T> 
sequence<T>::sequence (std::initializer_list<T> source)
  : sequence(source.size()) 
{
  auto it = source.begin();
  auto const e = source.cend();
  auto d = data_;
  while (it != e) {
     *d++ = *it++;
  } 
};
```

That way you don't explicitly rely on the `size()`.  You could consider making things more efficient by turning the `it` and `e` iterators into "move" iterators:

```
auto it = std::make_move_iterator(source.begin());
auto e = std::make_move_iterator(source.end());
```

That way, whenever it's dereferenced, its value is cast to an rvalue reference, allowing a move assignment.